# Number of avaliable ips in azure subnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am looking for number of available IP addresses in each subnet in azure vnet
so I am trying below script but I am not getting any option to get available IP.

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name TST-VNET1 -ResourceGroupName TST-RG1
$nic.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
$subnets= $nic.Subnets
$subnets
foreach( $subnet in $subnets)
{
$subnet.Name
$subnet.IpConfigurations.Count
$subnet.AddressPrefix
}
```

Using `$subnet.IpConfigurations.Count` gets the usable IP addresses. `$subnet.AddressPrefix` gets the cidr.

I am looking here available or assigned host IP addresses in each subnet pool.

Comment: I edited your question and embedded your image properly. Now, please move that comment into your question, as an edit. That doesn't belong in a comment (and it's pretty much unreadable as-is because it's unformatted).

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestion, but i am not true coder so this mistake done..

Comment: HI Jason thanks for your answer but this not i am looking for, i am looking for available ip in each subnet like you mention in screen shot

Answer (score 1):

We can use **Azure portal** to get the number of available IP addresses:
[image]

PowerShell script:

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name "jason" -ResourceGroupName "vnet"
$nic.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
$subnets = $nic.Subnets
$subnets
foreach( $subnet in $subnets)
{
$subnet.Name
$subnet.IpConfigurations.Count
$subnet.AddressPrefix
}

$splitAddress = $subnet.AddressPrefix.Split("/") 
$output = [math]::Pow(2, (32 - $splitAddress[1])) - 5 - $subnet.IpConfigurations.Count
```

Comment: $output.'Ip in Use' = $subnet.IpConfigurations.Count

     $splitAddress = $subnet.AddressPrefix.Split("/")

     $output.'Free IP in Subnet' = [math]::Pow(2, (32 - $splitAddress[1])) - 5 - $subnet.IpConfigurations.Count

Using above script i get the result...

Comment: @VivekMishra yes, your script is correct, it will get the number of available ip address.